# Why people use InputStream for loading files from assets folder but FileInputStream when loading files from internal storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Why people use InputStream for loading files from assets folder but use FileInputStream when loading files from internal storage ?
Can't I just use FileInputStream for both the cases ?

NOTE : I am a beginner in both Android and Java Programming Language.
In Java I've used FileInputStream for File Handling purposes though.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't I just use FileInputStream for both the cases ?

No. Assets are files on your development machine, but they are not files on the device. Assets are entries in the APK file on the device, rather than being files on the filesystem.